# i am getting an error while using app bundler in ant

Tags: java, macos, ant, app-bundle

When I am going to create .app file using app bundler in ant it gives an error given below:

```
/Users/vijaygupta/NetBeansProjects/Screen Grabber/build.xml:14: Problem: failed to create task or type bundleapp
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

My build.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Screen_Project" default="default" basedir=".">        
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

<taskdef name="Screen_Project"
         classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
         classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="ScreenProject">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
        name="ScreenProject"
        displayname="ScreenGrabber"
        identifier="Main.MainIconPage"
        mainclassname="Main.MainIconPage">
        <classpath file="dist/Screen_Project.jar" />
    </bundleapp>
</target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your build.xml does not contain a taskdef for the bundleapp tag. From the example above its clear you've changed it to Screen_Project and you simply need to replace the taskdef with this:

```
<taskdef name="bundleapp"
     classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
     classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />
```